# Call function in onchange on ion-slider not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, uislider

I'm call function update() in event onchange. I don't know where my mistake in my code. Need I change other slider in angular?

```
      <div ng-repeat="header in tempParams" style="padding: 5px;">
            <h5 ng-show="header.visible">{{header.title}}</h5>
            <div ng-show="header.visible">
                <ion-slider type="single"
                            grid="false"
                            min="header.minV"
                            max="header.maxV"
                            from="header.value"
                            disable="false"
                            onchange="update()">
                </ion-slider>
            </div>

        </div>
```

In Ctrl.js

```
$scope.update = function () { console.log("read") };
```

Error in log
[image]

Comment: Check whether you include ctrl.js

Comment: replace onchange with ng-change and have a check

Comment: Can you not specify onChange action when defining the ion-slider in the controller? Look into documentation.

Comment: @TamilSelvanC yes I already include a ctrl.js. ng-repeat in my html going fine , only onchange have problem.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk I'm trying to find the doc, but I never found correct document. Did you have a that document.

Comment: @Suresh yes I replace but still got error.